# Spring Boot serialization of Instant through MessageConverters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, jackson-databind

I'm trying to figure out how to configure the ObjectMapper inside the RestTemplate's default MessageConverters to serialize Instants as an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted String instead of a number. I'd like to avoid having to annotate every Instant in my models.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public String get(@RequestBody String object) {
        return object;
    }

    public String send(TestObject object) {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder().rootUri("http://localhost:8080").defaultMessageConverters().build()
            .exchange("/test", HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(object, headers()), String.class).getBody();
    }

    private HttpHeaders headers() {
        final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return httpHeaders;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class TestObject {
        private Instant test;
    }
}
```

I would like this test to pass given the code above

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class InstantTest {

    @Autowired
    private DemoApplication client;

    @Test
    public void name() {
        final String time = "2018-10-09T12:00:00.000Z";
        final String response = client.send(new DemoApplication.TestObject(Instant.parse(time)));
        assertThat(response).contains(time);
    }
}
```

The example uses jackson 2.9.6 and Spring Boot 2.0.5.
I've tried

- Disabling WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS on the auto configured ObjectMapper
- Using spring.jackson.serialization.write_date_timestamps_as_nanoseconds=false
- Providing a Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer @Bean disabling WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS
- Providing custom Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder

I'm obviously missing something since this feels like something that should be default behavior, or at least easily configurable.

Comment: Spring mvc already supported the configuration for jackson converter: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-message-converters

Comment: I don't think that would provide customization of the ObjectMapper used by the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter in the RestTemplate. At least I can't get that solution working. The only remotely reasonable solution I got working is get the default message converters from RestTemplate, remove the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter from that list of converters and then add my correctly configured MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter. Then use that list when i configure my RestTemplateBuilder. Though, feels like there should be an easier solution to customize this.

Comment: you can provide your bean MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter  and replace it in the default message converter through the hook action. Just iterate and check instance of MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter .

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own RestTemplate with Custom RestTemplateBuilder and achieve this.

For e.g.

```
@Configuration
public class Config{
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate  restTemplate() {
        RestTemplateBuilder builder = new RestTemplateBuilder();
        //You can initialize your custom message converter here;
        HttpMessageConverter<?> messageConverters = new  MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        builder.messageConverters(messageConverters);
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

You can have your own MessageConvertor to serialize instansts as ISO 8601.

For further reading follow this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-builder).